# Google Maps Label Infobox opening on external link?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create a webpage that has a Google Maps API within it with four markers, which can be clicked to open an Infobox each with it's own information. This works completely fine, however I also have images below the map which I would like to link to the Google Maps API and open the marker each link represents, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I've tried having a look at other such questions and tried their answers but I don't know how to implement it into my own code.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.487509,-2.240009),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions);

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    var myLocations = [
        ["Manchester Town Hall", "This magnificent building was designed in Victorian Gothic style by Alfred Waterhouse and opened in 1877. Amongst its many treasures are the Ford Maddox Brown murals which are monument to the ideas of Victorian Manchester, portraying science, invention, education, trade and textile industry.", "townhall.jpg", "http://www.manchester.gov.uk/", 53.479366, -2.244671],
        ["Manchester Royal Exchange Theatre", "Situated in the heart of Manchester, the Royal Exchange is an award-winning producing Theatre with a history spanning five decades. Known for producing classics such as William Shakespeare, we're also one of the country's leading theatres for new writing, with over 125 premieres in the theatre history!", "royalexchange.jpg", "http://www.royalexchange.co.uk/",  53.482696, -2.244588],
        ["Afflecks's Palace", "Afflecks is an emporium of eclecticism in Manchester’s Northern Quarter. A fantastic place to shop for anything unique, handmade or quirky! With over 73 units filled with individual sellers, you'll be sure to find something you love, or something for someone else!", "afflecks.jpg", "http://www.afflecks.com/", 53.482677, -2.23634],
        ["The Printworks", "The Printworks is a buzzing, state of the art entertainment complex located in the heart of Manchester City Centre. It is home to a range of restaurants, bars and clubs alongside a cinema and gym. The Printworks has something to offer both day and night.", "printworks.jpg", "http://www.theprintworks.com/", 53.485061, -2.241509]
        ];


    function infoCallback(infowindow, marker) { 
        return function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    };
   }    

   function setMarkers(map, myLocations) {  
    for (var i in myLocations)     {                                        
        var name    = myLocations[i][0];
        var info    = myLocations[i][1];
        var image   = myLocations[i][2];
        var url     = myLocations[i][3];
        var lat     = myLocations[i][4];
        var lng     = myLocations[i][5];
        var latlngset;
        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
          map: map,  title: name,  position: latlngset  
        });


        var content = 
        '<div class="mapContent"><h3>' + name + '</h3>' + '<img width="192" height="128" src="images/' + image + '"> <div class="mapContentText">' + info + '</div> <h4><a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a></h4> </div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          infowindow.setContent(content);
          google.maps.event.addListener(
            marker, 
            'click',
            infoCallback(infowindow, marker)
          );
      }
    }           
    setMarkers(map, myLocations);
  };
```

And the snippit of HTML with the map and the the images that appear below it that I would like to individually link to their respective map markers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA5Iwz01YK3kUnBKFSB7W0PML2XcIChJCc&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="js/mapScript.js"></script>       
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">

    <section id="mapContainer">
    </section>

    <img src="images/tag_townhall.jpg">
    <img src="images/tag_royalexchange.jpg">
    <img src="images/tag_printworks.jpg">
    <img src="images/tag_afflecks.jpg">
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the same click-listener to the corresponding image.

**1.** add a name-attribute to be able to select the images

```
<img name="someName" src="images/tag_townhall.jpg">
<img name="someName" src="images/tag_royalexchange.jpg">
<img name="someName" src="images/tag_printworks.jpg">
<img name="someName" src="images/tag_afflecks.jpg">
```

**2.** add the Listener:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(
  document.getElementsByName('someName')[i], 
  'click',
  infoCallback(infowindow, marker)
);
```